# How can I redirect node page for a content type to custom URL?

Tags: 8, redirection

I need to redirect all the pages for a content type to a custom URL in Drupal 8.

I used to do this in Drupal 7 by implementing `hook_init()` with the function `drupal_goto()` or by using the Rules module. Unfortunately both `hook_init()` and `drupal_goto()` are removed in Drupal 8, and the Rules module is not stable yet, and I can't figure out how to do it in Drupal 8.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You should look at the [Change Records](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal) to learn about alternatives to removed functions/hooks. Specifically https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014 has an example extremely similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @mradcliffe, actually I already tried to add Event Subscriber like in   https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014 but the problem was in detecting the content type of the node in the node page. anyway, I managed to solve this issue and I added an answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is how I managed to solve this issue, based on the example in [drupal.org/node/2013014](https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014):

I registered Event Subscriber in my_redirect_module.services.yml file:

```
   services:
     my_redirect_module_event_subscriber:
     class: Drupal\hbmsu_redirect\EventSubscriber\MyRedirectModuleSubscriber
     tags:
       - {name: event_subscriber}
```

and then in the file `my_redirect_module/src/EventSubscriber/MyRedirectModuleSubscriber.php`

I added this code:

```
  namespace Drupal\my_redirect_module\EventSubscriber;

  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
  use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

  class MyRedirectModuleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

      public function checkForRedirection(GetResponseEvent $event) {

          $baseUrl = $event->getRequest()->getBaseUrl();
          $attr = $event->getRequest()->attributes;
          if(null !== $attr &&
             null !== $attr->get('node') &&
             $attr->get('node')->get('type')->getString() == 'my_content_type') {
              $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($baseUrl.'/some_internal_url_path'));
          }
      }

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      static function getSubscribedEvents() {
          $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkForRedirection');
          return $events;
      }

  }
```

in `checkForRedirection` function, I'm checking if the page is for a node with the content type `my_content_type`, then redirect to the page `mywebsite.com/some_internal_url_path`

Comment: For me this broke node editing. To fix, assert `$attr->get('_entity_form') !== 'node.edit'` before redirecting.

Comment: As per @LincolnBergeson, there should be a test for node "sub-tabs", Josh Fremer has a nice clean walkthrough here: https://www.thirdandgrove.com/redirecting-node-pages-drupal-8

Comment: Works fine, though GetResponseEvent is deprecated since Symfony 4.3, use RequestEvent instead

Answer (score 1):

If you need to redirect from a custom form or an existing form (login, logout,...)=> (I assume this is what you want as you ask redirecting from a content type, I think you mean "after editing a content type");

then you can use

```
$form_state->setRedirect('user.page');
```

you can add this code in your form_alter, form_submit functions of your content type that you need to redirect

You can find some doc: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormSubmitterInterface.php/function/FormSubmitterInterface%3A%3AredirectForm/8.2.x

Like this example:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical',
 array('node' => 123),
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'foo' => 'bar',
    ),
    'fragment' => 'baz',
  ),
```

));

Comment: Thanks @Baud, actually in my case I don't have form submission. I wanted to redirect all the node pages for certain content type to another page created with Views has a list of all these contents. anyway, I found the solution for this issue and I added an answer here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rabbit hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) and [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) modules. With [Rabbit hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) you will be able to set a Page Redirect for the content type, and with [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) you can choose a field where users will be redirected when they try to access to a node.

Comment: If the nodes need to be secure, rabbit hole is the better option. It will block the node on more levels than what you could do with only using a Subscriber.

Comment: Yes, Rabbit hole module. Superb.. also one more module available https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Entity Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_redirect) module

That module provides a UI configurable redirect after saving a node or other entity and works for both Drupal 8, 9, 10.

Provides four different types of redirection:

```
Default: This will not impact the entity but will just go to the default.
Add Form: Redirect to a new add form for the content type/entity.
Local Url: provide a local url in the form of /about to go to any page on the site.
External Url: Same as local url but to an external location. Note: this is only available to users with the permission set external entity redirects.
```

. For example for the Node type Article that would be at /admin/structure/types/manage/article, click on Publishing options, you will see a **REDIRECT AFTER ENITY OPERATIONS**
[image]