# Earliest point in page load to issue a redirect?

Tags: 8

I'd like to redirect all of the paths for my media entities the path of a file on the entity. What hook would allow me to do this as early in the page load process as possible?

Comment: This depends on some details, is this for anonymous or logged in users, is it static so that it can be cached or dynamic and you don't want it to be cached. What services should already be loaded, for example do you need user authentication or the route resolved? So each case is different, but if you ask what is really the earliest point, then this would be a middleware before the Drupal Kernel is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an EventSubscriber! [This post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/202477/48114) gives a pretty good code example.

I'm doing exactly this and I had some issues when the media's file changes, the redirect will be cached and still point to the old file. To get around this I use the [page_cache_kill_switch](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PageCache%21ResponsePolicy%21KillSwitch.php/class/KillSwitch/8.2.x) service which you can inject into your subscriber or just call like:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

One other note is that you'll want to make sure you only fire the redirect when the route `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.media.canonical'`. This will make sure you only redirect when trying to *view* the entity vs edit or etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've just about got this working. Can't quite figure out how to check against `entity.media.canonical` using the post from above. How would I check that against `$current_route`?

Comment: `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteId() == 'entity.media.canonical'`  I think. Will follow up later (on mobile)

Comment: Actually `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.media.canonical'`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In place of the code in the post linked by @sonfd, I ended up using:

```
$baseUrl = $event->getRequest()->getBaseUrl();
$attr = $event->getRequest()->attributes;
$current_route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();

if($current_route == 'entity.media.canonical' && null !== $attr && null !== $attr->get('media')) {
  switch($attr->get('media')->bundle()){
    case 'image':
      $file_field = $attr->get('media')->get('field_image')->getValue();
    break;
    case 'document':
      $file_field = $attr->get('media')->get('field_file')->getValue();
    break;
  }
  $file_field = reset($file_field);
  $fid = $file_field['target_id'];
  $file = Url::fromUri(
    File::load($fid)->url()
  );
  $url = $file->getUri();
  $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
```

Comment: Make sure you only fire the cache kill switch inside your if statement for media entities, otherwise you're going to kill cache on every kernel request (boo! :) ). Your event subscriber is just saying "add this event when we get a kernel request" so this will fire on every page, it's not until you check for the media information that you're only acting on media routes vs node, views, etc routes. Also, it doesn't look like you're using the `$baseUrl` var.

Comment: Yes, this is not a good idea to disable the cache for the whole site. But even for this specific route you should only disable the cache if the behavior is dynamic/random. Here the response depends on entity data and is static as long as the entities are not modified, so you should make the response cacheable by using `CacheableRedirectResponse` and add the cacheable dependencies of the media and file entities.

Comment: Right, I see now that I am killing the cache everywhere. If I left everything as it is without designating an alteration to cache behavior, will the redirect go to the proper place if a file is changed since the media entity will be updated, or do I need to actually define `CacheableRedirectResponse`?

Comment: You need `CacheableRedirectResponse`, so that you can add the media entity `->addCacheableDependency($media)`, otherwise the response will get cached without being tagged and then you get a stale cache entry when the media is changed. Better add the file entity too, the url of the file could be modified without touching the parent media.