# Modify existing custom content form

Tags: forms, hooks

I'm very new to Drupal development and I am completely stuck(.

I have a custom content form, where I need to hide some fields in Inline Entity Form.
I am trying to write my own custom module to achieve this, I am doing the following:
1. I create module folder, where I put info.yml file
2. I create Controller file, where I add custom class and this code inside this class:

```
public function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {if ($form_id == 'MY_FORM') {...};
```

3. The next thing I am completely stuck at is do I need a routing file to make this work?
   I can't find any info about this so I'd really appreciate some help!
   And if I need routing, what should I write there?

Comment: You don't need to involve routing to make the `hook_form_alter` work, I suggest you find a simple tutorial or example and start with that. 
 Look here https://befused.com/drupal/form-alter or  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163607/alter-an-existing-form start with anyone of those and make it work before diving into your problem. Than post a question with something more specific and your relevant code.

Comment: This is very close to what you want https://mushtaq.ch/blog/10/drupal-8-disable-or-hide-a-form-field but I suspect its not exactly the same as your problem involves `inline_entity_form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much! 
I really didn't need routing!

Well, finally I found the solution to my problem - I created the module with 2 files only - mymodule.info.yml and mymodule.module.
In .module file I only added these lines of code and everything worked! (Almost)

```
function mymodule_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter(&$entity_form, &$form_state) { 
if ($entity_form['#entity_type'] == 'node' && $entity_form['#bundle'] == 'my_custom_content_type_machine_name') { 
  unset($entity_form['field_I_need_to_hide']); 
}}
```

Comment: This is great news that you went this far.  Providing this as answer will mostly prevent people from posting any answer especially since your new question is in AN ANSWER.  I think you should either consider editing the question with your new findings or create a new.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will create new question!